# How do I configure the pom.xml of Tika to stop getting all the license dependency warnings?

Tags: java, maven, pdfbox, apache-tika

I am getting all these warnings from Tika when I try to use it:

> Feb 24, 2018 9:24:35 PM
>   org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3
>   handleInitializableProblem WARNING: JBIG2ImageReader not loaded. jbig2
>   files will be ignored See
>   https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#jai-image-io for
>   optional dependencies. TIFFImageWriter not loaded. tiff files will not
>   be processed See
>   https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#jai-image-io for
>   optional dependencies. J2KImageReader not loaded. JPEG2000 files will
>   not be processed. See
>   https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#jai-image-io for
>   optional dependencies.
>
> Feb 24, 2018 9:24:35 PM
>   org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3
>   handleInitializableProblem WARNING: org.xerial's sqlite-jdbc is not
>   loaded. Please provide the jar on your classpath to parse sqlite
>   files. See tika-parsers/pom.xml for the correct version.

I tried adding this (in Tika pom.xml):

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
                <version>1.57</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
                <version>1.57</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
                <version>1.57</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.levigo.jbig2</groupId>
                <artifactId>levigo-jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
                <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
                <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>3.20.1</version>
            </dependency>
```

But I still get the same warnings.

How do I resolve this?

**UPDATE 1**

My dependencies were added here: https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/1.17/pom.xml#L164-L170

Also I did try without the  set to test. It did not do anything.

The dependencies that I added seemed to be for PDFBox a Tika dependency.

Comment: How did you get the idea to include the three dependencies as scope `test`? I'm asking to find out whether this is a documentation problem somewhere.

Comment: Actually the first time I try it I did remove the scope test.

Comment: That is the pom to build tika... not to use it. Tika doesn't distribute these jar files because of "bad" license.

Comment: To check whether your plugins are in your class path, run this code: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes()));`

Answer (score 9):

I added the following dependencies and I didn't have any other warning

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Note that jai-imageio-jpeg2000 has JJ2000 license: "only "JJ2000 Partners" have
the right to use and modify".

Answer (score 2):

For Clojure visitors: I fixed it with:

```
(System/setProperty "tika.config" "tika-config.xml")
```

in my config.clj file. The xml is just:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
   <service-loader initializableProblemHandler="ignore"/>
</properties>
```

this xml file is in the "resources" dir and that dir must be in your path.

Comment: Works also for java client, tika version 1.25, and load this config like this: `new TikaConfig(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/tika-config.xml"));`

Comment: It does not fix the problem right? But "just" hide it so no warning anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to see exactly what is happening because you did not include your entire `<dependencies>...</dependencies>` section of your pom.xml, but I suspect it is due to optional maven dependencies.  According to [maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html), you need to  declare optional dependencies in your pom or they will not be loaded.

Additionally, all of your imageio dependencies are all have `<scope>test</scope>` making them only usable during unit testing.

Comment: I tried scope without test. It did not do anything. The rest of <dependencies> is the same has the default of Tika.

Comment: Here is the default pom.xml I am using: https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/1.17/pom.xml

Comment: How are you using Tika?  It appears that you can use Tika in a lot of different ways: https://tika.apache.org/1.17/gettingstarted.html

Comment: I am using the pom.xml of tika itself. I am just installing it (mvn install).

Answer (score 0):

this is now documented in the error log:

> Feb 19, 2019 3:18:44 PM org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
>   WARNING: J2KImageReader not loaded. JPEG2000 files will not be processed.
>   See https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#jai-image-io
>   for optional dependencies.

However I'd prefer to have a version of Tika (e.g., with a classifier) which does not include OCR/image processing when I only want to parse text, or have an option to turn off the error logging (and only log an error when actually trying to load an unsupported format).