# while invoking ctakes parser from tika-app getting exception

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, apache-tika, ctakes

While invoking cTAKES parser from tika-app getting following:

```
java -classpath $HOME/src/ctakes-config:${TIKA_HOME}/tika-app/target/tika-app-X.Y-SNAPSHOT.jar:${CTAKES_HOME}/desc:${CTAKES_HOME}/resources:${CTAKES_HOME}/lib/* org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI --config=$HOME/src/ctakes-config/tika-config.xml -m Vose-2013-American_Journal_of_Hematology.pdf
```

**Exception**

Screenshot of Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

[image]

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel.getMaxentModel()Lopennlp/model/AbstractModel;

I have followed the steps mentioned in [this link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/CTAKESParser). I am unable to understand the cause of this error and hence how to resolve this.

I am also getting following warning:
**Warning**

> Feb 16, 2020 12:19:58 PM org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
>   WARNING: J2KImageReader not loaded. JPEG2000 files will not be processed.
>   See https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#jai-image-io
>   for optional dependencies.
>
> Feb 16, 2020 12:19:59 PM org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
>   WARNING: org.xerial's sqlite-jdbc is not loaded.
>   Please provide the jar on your classpath to parse sqlite files.
>   See tika-parsers/pom.xml for the correct version.

I have tried to resolve it using answers in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970160/how-do-i-configure-the-pom-xml-of-tika-to-stop-getting-all-the-license-dependency), but it wasn't of much help. i know these are only warnings and hope are not causing the error 
and am using tika only by installing it

**System Information**

- OS  ubuntu 16.04
- JDK  openJDK8.
- Maven 3.3.9
- Apache tika 1.23
- Apache cTAKES 3.2.2

Comment: Can you post your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Looks like you have incompatible versions of cTakes and Tika, which want conflicting opennlp versions.

Answer (score 1):

I've  addressed  this. It had to do with incompatible versions  of  the Apache OpenNLP library. The Tika CTAKES parser was pinned to 1.5.3, and cTAKES 3.2.2 uses that version, but Tika Parsers has since evolved  to use a newer version.

The fix was to reference the  older  OpenNLP 1.5.3 jar in  the  classpath.  I  have updated the  wiki here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/CTAKESParser

```
java -classpath $HOME/src/ctakes-config:${CTAKES_HOME}/lib/opennlp-tools-1.5.3.jar:${TIKA_HOME}/tika-app/target/tika-app-X.Y-SNAPSHOT.jar:${CTAKES_HOME}/desc:${CTAKES_HOME}/resources:${CTAKES_HOME}/lib/\* org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI \
--config=$HOME/src/ctakes-config/tika-config.xml \
-m Vose-2013-American_Journal_of_Hematology.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to invoke cTAKES from tika app after installing Apache tika-1.10
Both versions of cTAKES and TIKA were incompatible